# Android app keep audio playing when screen is off

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Is there any way to let my self coded android app (it uses webview to display a webpage) continue playing the audio from a webview webpage even if the screen is turned off?

I couldn't find a working solution for android 13 online.
But from what I have read I think I have to use a foreground Service.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the audio playing even when the screen is turned off, you will need to use a foreground service.

Very roughly, these are the steps to implement a foreground service in your app:

1. Create a new class that extends `Service`.
2. Override the `onCreate()` method and start a foreground service notification using `startForeground()`. Customize it to your liking.
3. In the `onStartCommand()` method of your service, create and configure your `WebView` instance. Enable Javascript and other settings to allow audio playback.
4. Also, in the `onStartCommand()` method, create and start a **new thread** to handle the loading of your web page in the WebView instance. Use this separate thread so that the WebView can continue to load the page while your service runs in the background.
5. In your activity, bind to the service using `bindService()`, and then call methods on the service to control the WebView instance as needed.

If you need actual example code, please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot for answering.
I think the idea to create an app for something already working(jellyfin-android app) got too complicated for me, I thought the background playback would work natively, but that seems to complicated for my first ever android/java project.

My initial idea was to automate the process to start tailscale vpn, basically as soon as I start the jellyfin app the vpn should launch, so the client can connect remotely.
This however seems easier to implement directly into the app made by the developers, because they are on github.

Answer (score 0):

When your application goes into the background, you can pause the web view and resume it when the page is opened again.

```
override fun onPause() {
    webView.onPause()
    super.onPause()

 override fun onResume() {
        super.onPause()
        webView.onResume()
    }
```

Comment: Why should I do that?

If I turn my phone's screen off or open another application the music from the corresponding webview page should continue to play rather than stop.